# Determine whether the following transformation is linear or not

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, linear-transformations

Q:T(x,y) = (y,y)

I have checked online resources and solved some questions but as per my worksheet regarding this Q. I am not able to understand how is this solved. My worksheet solution is below.

1. T(u+v) = T(x1+x2 , y1+y2)
   = ((y1+y2) , y1+y2)
   = T(u) + T(v)
2. cT(x, y) = c(y, y) = (cy, cy)

Q1: As per my textbook , i had to prove T(a+b) = T(a) + T(b). So , T(a) does not match. One is x1+x2 and another is y1+y2. So , shouldnt we say its not a linear transformation ? How is it proved that y1 + y2 = x1 + x2 ?

Hence proved , it is a linear transformation.

Comment: It's not proved that $y_1+y_2=x_1+x_2$, but $\color{blue}T(x_1+x_2,y_1+y_2)=(y_1+y_2,y_1+y_2)$ given the definition of $T$

Comment: @J.W.Tanner Thnx for your comment but… I still dont get what you meant. I have edited my question more to clarify what i meant. It would be helpful if u could provide a answer with more details. Thnx

Comment: Hi! Use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference/15078#15078) for equations

Comment: I'm not sure what you don't get.  Does it help you to say $\dots=(y_1+y_2,y_1+y_2)=\color{blue}{(y_1,y_1)+(y_2,y_2)=}T(u)+T(v)$, where $u=(x_1,y_1)$ and $v=(x_2,y_2)$?

Comment: How is y1,y1 = T(u) ? Isnt T(u) = x1,y1 @J.W.Tanner

Comment: No, $u=(x_1,y_1)$, but $T(u)=(y_1,y_1)$ by the definition you gave for $T$

Answer (score 1):

Let $u = (x_1, y_1), v = (x_2, y_2)$.

Then we have:

$T(u+v) = T(x_1+x_2 , y_1+y_2) 
          = (y_1+y_2 , y_1+y_2) = (y_1, y_1) + (y_2, y_2) = T(x_1, y_1) + T(x_2, y_2) 
          = T(u) + T(v) $

Comment: Could you please explain more like the concept along with the question. Its difficult to understand like this. I am not getting how is this working.

Comment: The concept of what? The definition of linear transformation? If $T$ is linear, the following have to hold: $$T(x+y) = T(x) + T(y)$$ and $$T(cz) = c T(z)$$ for any $c \in \Bbb{R}$